# disable services on startup in ubuntu

Tags: startup

I installed these applications on my Ubuntu:

- nginx
- php5-fpm
- mysql server
- redis
- ...

These applications run every time the computer turns on.

How can I prevent these applications from running on start up?
So, these applications only run if I do "service nginx start".

Comment: `for s in "nginx mysql redis"; do sudo update-rc.d $s disable; done`

Comment: Auto-start programs are configured in `autostart` manifests or in `*.service` files in several locations, as well as in `init.d` or `crontab`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/525845/43233

Answer (score 167):

Use:

```
systemctl disable <service>
```

If you are not using systemd (Ubuntu 14.10 and earlier) use:

```
update-rc.d -f <service> remove
```

The following command will give you a list of all services on your machine:

```
service --status-all
```

You should be able to find the names of the services you want to disable in there.

For more details, see [enabling-and-disabling-services](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/04/enabling-and-disabling-services-during_01.html) and for the very long answer see this [post](https://askubuntu.com/q/19320/425630) (as already mentioned by @muru).

For more details, see this post on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units) and the [man page](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html) for systemctl.

Comment: Starting with Ubuntu 15, this is no longer valid.  `systemctl disable SERVICE` works (see the linked question in answer)

Comment: The link in "For more details see ..." does not mention systemctl. I guess that was for old versions, but now it's confusing.

Comment: @matteo Up dated my answer with links to posts with more info on systemctl

Answer (score -1):

Another method is by installing rcconf `apt-get install rcconf`. From rcconf you can enable/disable any service that is installed on your ubuntu/debian server.

Comment: Except of course that it uses functionality of `update-rc.d` that was removed a few years ago (Debian bug #727735) and it doesn't work with systemd or upstart, i.e. either of the default init systems for Ubuntu Linux for the past decade.

Answer (score -1):

Install `sysv-rc-conf`

```
apt-get install sysv-rc-conf
```

Then simply to list services

```
sysv-rc-conf --list
```

To disable any services i.e nginx

```
sysv-rc-conf nginx off
```

For more information see `man sysv-rc-conf`

Comment: Except of course that it doesn't work with systemd or upstart.  It is patently (it even being in the package name) only for the old System 5 rc system, which hasn't been the default on Ubuntu Linux for almost a decade.  Debian Bug #791689 acknowledges this and questions why it hasn't been marked as conflicting with systemd.