# Httpd is not present in init.d

Tags: apache2

I have installed lamp on Ubuntu 15.10. Apache is working fine. Whenever i tried to start the server it says.
bash: /etc/init.d/httpd: No such file or directory.
Please help.

Comment: What command did you run to start the server?

Comment: $/etc/init.d/httpd start

Comment: Ah, current versions of Ubuntu use systemd and the start command is `sudo systemctl start apache2.service` and for earlier versions using upstart the command is `sudo service apache2 start`. Ubuntu hasn't used `/etc/init.d/` for starting services for quite a while now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable or disable services?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$/etc/init.d/httpd start will not work on Ubuntu, Debian/Ubuntu support listed  below commands and CentOS/RHEL support *service httpd restart*:

How to start Apache 2:

```
 sudo service apache2 start
```

How to stop Apache 2:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

How to restart Apache 2:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

How to reload Apache 2:

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please tell me how do i run perl programs on the server.

Comment: @GouthamSridhar If you have new question please ask it by clicking on the [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.

Comment: I appreciated it.