# Disable Docker autostart at boot?

Tags: boot, mount, autostart, docker

I was trying to experiment with `docker`, Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit. I managed to run an image, and I gave it the path on one of my removable drives, `/media/Drive1`.

Now, whenever I reboot, I see there is a `/media/Drive1` with only a `docker` directory inside it, and the actual drive which should be `Drive1` ends up mounted on `/media/Drive11`, and this happens every reboot - even when I unmount these drives, and do a `sudo rm -rfv /media/Drive1` before rebooting!

So something probably creates `/media/Drive1` before it is fully mounted, and I guess that something is `docker`, because when I boot, I have:

```
$ ps axf | grep docker
 2085 ?        Ssl    0:00 /usr/bin/docker -d
```

So, how can I disable the `docker` autostart, so it doesn't interfere with the mounting of external USB drives at boot?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I think I managed to get it working, following [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo manual | sudo tee /etc/init/docker.override'
```

Hope that was it...

Answer (score 85):

On the systems since Ubuntu 16.04+ (where OS uses `systemd`), according to the [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/linux-postinstall/#/systemd), autostart on boot can be turned off by:

```
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.service
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.socket
```

or as @Burak said in the comment, here is the one liner command:

```
sudo systemctl disable docker.service docker.socket
```

Note that if you do not disable the socket as well as the service then the service will get started anyways as the socket depends on it.

Comment: In my case, I had to disable `docker-volume-local-persist.service` and `docker.socket` as well. To list any *docker* service in systemd, type: `systemctl list-unit-files | grep -i docker`

Comment: I had to reinstall docker after this because `docker-compose up` wouldn't work anymore

Comment: You can use one-liner `sudo systemctl disable docker.service docker.socket`

Comment: @Taylor FYI you just had to re-enable the service: `sudo systemctl enable docker.service docker.socket`

Answer (score 2):

This is for recent Ubuntu releases using `systemctl`.

To disable on boot, use `systemctl disable` as @Burak said:

```bash
sudo systemctl disable docker.service docker.socket
```

This will have the side-effect of stopping Docker from working at all after a reboot, as @Taylor found. You will get an error like this:

```bash
~$ sudo docker container ls
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

To start the Docker service in a script or at the prompt without re-enabling it to start at boot, use `systemctl start`:

```
sudo systemctl start docker.service
```

You can then use `docker` or `docker-compose` as normal, and it will still not automatically restart on boot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to apply `mask` to the service:

```
sudo systemctl mask docker
```

Comment: Which will disable the docker service completely, until you manually "unmask" it.