# Syslog is taking up all my space!

Tags: syslog

I was having a issue with something taking up my memory and not letting me boot, I have found the culprit - it’s my `syslog` file in /var. It’s now 170 GB!

I deleted `syslog.1` which was 64GB but it has only made things much worse because `syslog` is now 10x bigger.

From what I have read online so far it’s because a repeating error in the file. The error I’m getting is:

```
docker.dockerd[1128]: time="2019-11-17T03:06:48.667249945+11:00"
level=error msg="failed to get event" error="rpc error: code =
Unavailable desc = all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest
connection error: connection error: desc = \"transport: Error while
dialing dial unix /run/containerd/containerd.sock: connect: permission
denied\"" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
```

I have no idea what this means but it’s taking up all space again and now I can't boot again, I will try and delete what little other files I have so that I can hopefully boot again but I need some help ASAP on getting this `syslog` file fixed. Sorry if I seem impatient I’m just really starting to worry.

Comment: As a stopgap, you should disable the docker service until you find out why it's spamming the syslog (bet your journal is getting overwhelmed as well). See https://askubuntu.com/questions/766318/disable-docker-autostart-at-boot#880205.

Answer (score 0):

**booting**

If you cannot boot into the GUI mode, you can choose the `recovery mode` from your Grub menu.

Choose `root` mode - then go your log directory and delete the syslog file.

You should be able to boot into the GUI mode again.

**get rid of the root problem**

I neither know what the error message means, but it is clearly issued by the docker demon.

I'd suggest to deinstall docker for now.

Then you have time to google for the reason or try to get help elsewhere.