# Very poor graphics performance after suspend for Nvidia Optimus on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, suspend, nvidia-optimus

I see a dramatic drop in GPU graphics performance on my laptop after resume from a suspend-to-RAM.  Though I notice an overall drop in performance, my benchmark that I use is running TF2 via Steam, and checking both loading times and in-game fps.

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, hoping that might help, but it actually has made the problem worse...

My GPU is a Nvidia GeForce GTX 760M Optimus hybrid.  I am running `nvidia-361` driver, though have tried many different driver versions all with similar results.  My integrated graphics is running the `i915` driver.  I use `nvidia-prime` to

Typically, the game should load in < 20s and a similar time to load a map and I can get a stable 150-200fps in-game.  After a suspend/resume, it can take as long as 5 min to load the game and start a map.  FPS is then 45 with periodic (every 5s) drops to 2 or 3, rendering it quite unusable.  A fresh restart fixes it every time, though is getting rather tiresome.

I am not quite sure where I should be looking, I have run psensor on my GPU in both scenarios and do not notice any significant changes in GPU load / mem usage / temp.

It feels like the nvidia driver is not being used after the resume, as performance is pretty bad on the integrated GPU, though all indicators specify it is indeed being loaded.

Some hopefully useful info:

- [dmesg - after reboot](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22857731/)
- [dmesg - after suspend/resume](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22857767/)
- [lspci -vv](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22857878/)
- [modinfo nvidia_361](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22858518/)
- [modinfo i915](http://paste.ubuntu.com/22858550/)

I've reached the limit of my debugging prowess and cannot determine what I should be looking for to see what is going on.  Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1 for putting that stuff on http://paste.ubuntu.com !

Comment: `pastebinit` is our friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

So for anyone who might happen upon this, I ended up solving the issue and wanted to give a quick response to what was wrong, and what to do to remedy.

To begin with, the real problem was that my CPU was overheating.  It was being asked to do too much and was not able to cool itself properly.  I ended up fixing my issue, and getting reproducible results on my Steam games.

1. Check your upstart/systemctl services.  I had a bunch of services that I never use daily enabled via upstart (ie postgres, mongodb, etc).  I ended up checking my running programs after a fresh boot and disabled these services one by one.  Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) for specifics on how to do this for your OS version.
2. Check any non standard CPU heavy services and ensure they are stopped before starting any games.  For me this was Dropbox, there was a noticeable drop in performance while the dropbox service was started, my guess is that it interrupts the CPU too often to check for any changes to my Dropbox files.  In any case, I disabled this to autostart (in the UI 'Startup Applications', which is where I put the autostart script.
3. Check and clean your cooling system.  I think a big part of my issue was that the fan was actually being pinched just slightly by the housing (laptop) and it was not spinning up to 100% on full power.  Obviously this resulted in a reduced ability to push hot air to the radiators and I could not cool the CPU / GPU properly.  I ensured smooth fan operation and give it a good clean with Compressed Dry Air about every month.  I notice a big improvement to stability during these high load times after a clean.

So those were the big things I did to ensure a consistent experience on my system when playing games were involved.  The fixes all seem to be straight forward and obvious in hindsight, but the combination of factors made it tough for me to isolate what is going wrong in the moment.

Hope this can help someone with similar griefs.