# What is a package stanza?

Tags: packaging, debian, binary, source-packages

Briefly speaking, how to define a package stanza?

It arrives by running `dpkg-gencontrol` in a package directory:

```
# dpkg-gencontrol                                 
dpkg-gencontrol: error: no package stanza found in control info
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a "state" where a package offers rules about how it should behave (install, upgrade, remove) and how it relates (eg: other packages or running services). This rules can be how to install it, how it depends on other packages, general information regarding the actual package and more.

When `dpkg-gencontrol` issues that type of error, it usually means that the package did not offer, or have any information to control what to do with said package. This information is typically found in what is called a "Control File" inside the package.

For the cases of Debian packages, you can find more information [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html) 
and from where the actual error description came from, I believe you can go [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=642473).

Note that stanzas (In computer terms I mean) can also mean states in which a service is at a specific moment. An example is found in [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services) when a service is stopped or started.