# /usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory

Tags: server, cron, ruby, paths, rvm

When crontab tries to execute the script:

```
@reboot sh /home/username/unicorn_start.sh > /home/username/unicorn_start.out 2>&1
```

It creates me a log file with the following content: `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory`.

This is what I have in **unicorn_start.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin"

/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start
```

If I execute **unicorn_myapp** or **unicorn_start.sh** manually, everything works fine. As I understand, I need to add an additional path to $PATH variable. What is the way of doing it? Thanks ahead.

**EDIT:**

**unicorn_init.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}
APP_ROOT=/home/username/appname
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT; bundle exec unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
AS_USER=root
set -u

OLD_PIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_PIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_PIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_PIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_PIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

Comment: Do you want to start a daemon (assuming from `/etc/init.d/`)? You should start it as a service in such a case, not using `cron`. https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services

Comment: When I start it like service:`sudo service unicorn_appname start`, it gives me an error:  `/etc/init.d/unicorn_appname: 1: eval: bundle: not found`

Comment: You should show us the code in `/etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp`. The code you’ve posted till now does not contain any call to `/usr/bin/env`.

Comment: `unicorn_myapp` is a symlink to `unicorn_init.sh` that is located in the rails project in `app/config` If you need the content of `unicorn_init.sh`, I'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 1):

The default PATH crontab is using is "only" `/usr/bin:/bin`, however you can adjust it.

Instead of writing the things in that script try adding it directly into the crontab command:

```
@reboot PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin"; /etc/init.d/unicorn_myapp start > /home/username/unicorn_start.out 2>&1
```

You can also add the path variable above every cronjob so it's applicable to every task you put in there:

```
 PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin"
 #
 #
 * * * * * myjob.sh
 @reboot /home/username/unicorn_start.sh > /home/username/unicorn_start.out 2>&1
```

Comment: Still, it gives me the same error: `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Which solution did you try?

Comment: The first one you wrote. EDIT: Tried the second solution, but the result didn't change.

Comment: Sounds more like an issue in your ruby script then cronjob issue. You can try the same with just a simple "echo $PATH" instead of your script and see what the PATH variable consists of or create a hello world ruby script and try piping that ouput into a file.

Comment: The output of `echo $PATH`: `/root/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/root/.rbenv/shims:/root/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
`

Comment: I ment putting it into your crontab instead of your unicorn script. So e.g. `@reboot echo $PATH > /tmp/crontab.path` reboot and see what you actually have as a PATH during the reboot. If you used the second one it should be the path that was set.

Comment: It gives me: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62922/discussion-between-ziazis-and-alex-zakruzhetskyi).

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue with following details

Ruby was installed on system

`which ruby` returned `/usr/local/bin/ruby`  but if is try to run any script from cron it was throwing error `/usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory`

A little investigation revealed that env was trying to load ruby binary form `/usr/bin/ruby` even though `/usr/local/bin/` was in the `$PATH` env variable. So i created a soft link.

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Now scripts can work from cron as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the which command you should be able to see where your ruby executable is located e.g

```
which ruby

/usr/bin/ruby
```

The you could add that path to the $PATH variable to straight to the crontab (not sure what best practice may dictate but has worked for me in the past)