# Why does Ubuntu 19.04 take so long to boot?

Tags: boot, kernel, boot-repair, 19.04, bug-reporting

My computer has lenovo 300, with Intel Core i7-6500U and Ubuntu 19.04 installed. It takes so long to boot, like 3 or 4 minutes and sometimes I have to turn off my computer because it freezes with a black screen (before a normal starting). I don't know what I have to do. (This machine has 4 GPU).

```
1min 2.617s plymouth-quit-wait.service
52.989s phpsessionclean.service
29.087s systemd-journal-flush.service
28.746s dev-sda1.device
22.509s snapd.service
19.692s networkd-dispatcher.service
19.513s ModemManager.service
18.659s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
18.241s accounts-daemon.service
17.646s apparmor.service
16.661s mysql.service
15.455s udisks2.service
15.373s dev-loop27.device
15.108s dev-loop30.device
15.060s dev-loop33.device
14.968s dev-loop36.device
14.948s dev-loop32.device
14.366s dev-loop34.device
14.365s dev-loop20.device
14.315s dev-loop35.device
14.209s dev-loop25.device
14.151s dev-loop29.device
13.840s plymouth-read-write.service
```

This is what it shows :( Idk what to do, and thanks for telling me how it works xd

Comment: At the boot screen with the dots, typing esc should switch to a screen with text progress/errors. Do you see anything there taking a long time?

Comment: After booting open a terminal and type `systemd-analyze blame` then copy the first screen of output (left click and drag mouse to highlight text, right click and select copy) and paste (right click - paste) into your question.

Comment: @ValantinaCampos I have a work computer that does this but it's 100% due to the hardware. it's some cheap Dell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using Ubuntu 15.04 or newer, you can disable individual services by running this command in a terminal:

```
sudo systemctl disable service-to-disable
```

For example, if you wanted to disable `snapd`:

```
sudo systemctl disable snapd
```

(Do not include the `.service` extension when referring to a service on systemctl.)

**Be careful when disabling a service, however! Some are critical and your system may fail to boot properly if disabled.** Research each service listed to determine its importance.

Comment: Source https://askubuntu.com/a/19324/961936

Comment: Do you know which services I can disable? And thanks ♡

Comment: If you have not used or installed Snap packages, or have no idea what Snap packages are, you can disable `snapd`. (That's why I used it as an example, since IMO it's pretty safe to disable.)

Comment: Also, you can even uninstall `snapd` by running `sudo apt uninstall snapd`.

Comment: Finally, this may sound bizarre, but apparently moving your mouse is supposed to speed up the `phpsessionclean` service: https://superuser.com/a/1350371/1046993

Comment: Thank you so much :( I'll do this later :')