# Can't disable netplan-ovs-cleanup.service

Tags: networking, 20.04, services

After installing all updates on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, I got this issue on monitoring. One of the `systemd` services is still failing, and I can't disable it.

```
● netplan-ovs-cleanup.service - OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup
 Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/netplan-ovs-cleanup.service; enabled-runtime; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
 Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2021-02-12 09:03:23 CET; 2h 22min ago
         └─ ConditionFileIsExecutable=/usr/bin/ovs-vsctl was not met

Feb 12 08:54:55 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
Feb 12 09:03:23 hostname systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in OpenVSwitch configuration for cleanup being skipped.
```

I was looking for some `.deb` packages to uninstall, but `dpkg` doesn't have any.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to disable any service using the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl disable servicename.service
sudo systemctl mask    servicename.service
```

The first disables the service. The second ensures the service doesn’t start up again later.

To restore the services, `unmask` and `enable`:

```
sudo systemctl unmask servicename.service
sudo systemctl enable servicename.service
```

Comment: After reboot it work excellent. Thanks