# How to Control the SSH Service

Tags: server, ssh, systemd, openssh

Ubuntu 20.04.

I have installed the openssh-server to test with ssh, but since then, whenever I boot up the system, the server starts running at port 22, which I feel is a security risk when I am connected with WiFi (and maybe it even hogs a lot of RAM).

So my questions are

- How to control from the terminal whether the service starts at boot. I understand it has something to do with systemd, but somewhat of a noob to know it. Basically what commands add or remove it from starting at booting?
- When the machine is powered on, what commands can start, stop, restart the service? I can kill the process by sending a signal, but wonder whether that is really a *graceful exit.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Comment: `systemctl disable ssh`, `systemctl [start|stop|restart] ssh`

Answer (score 0):

You can disable (so it doesn't start at boot) the service with

```
sudo systemctl disable ssh.service
```

then start it when needed with

```
sudo systemctl start ssh.service
```

To change the port edit

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The file has a commented port line