# How to disable a service only for the next boot?

Tags: startup, systemd, services, upstart

According to https://askubuntu.com/a/19324

`systemctl disable SERVICE` Turns the service off on the next reboot or on the next stop event. It persists after reboot.

Is it possible to disable a service just for the next boot?

I mean a one-shot disabling.

Comment: (untested) - maybe something along the lines of an /etc/systemd/system/service-name.d/override.conf that clears and then sets ExecStart to /bin/true, then removes itself (the override.conf file)?

Comment: I think that `systemctl stop service` will stop the service untill the next boot or the next `systemctl start service` command as you wish.