# How do I unmask mongod in Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, mongodb

I get this error with mongo on Ubuntu, how would I unmask it

```
 Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service is masked.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

Comment: `sudo systemctl unmask mongod` would be the command to use here - see question above. ^^