My systog file is 3GB with a systemd error every 2-3 seconds
In the last couple days Ive started getting a system freeze which needed a hard restart each time. After some online research I checked the syslog file and found it to be over 3 GB for just the last 5 days.
The errors every 2-3 seconds for the most part:
Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t systemd[1]: ollama.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 11377.
Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t systemd[1]: Stopped Ollama Service.
Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t systemd[1]: Started Ollama Service.
Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t systemd[1]: ollama.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t ollama[299476]: 2024/10/07 09:38:38 routes.go:1153: INFO server config env="map[CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES: GPU_DEVICE_ORDINAL: HIP_VISIBLE_DEVICES: HSA_OVERRIDE_GFX_VERSION: HTTPS_PROXY: HTTP_PROXY: NO_PROXY: OLLAMA_DEBUG:false OLLAMA_FLASH_ATTENTION:false O>
Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t ollama[299476]: Error: mkdir /mnt/disk1/ollama: permission denied
Oct 07 09:38:38 b3a5t systemd[1]: ollama.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Over and over tens of thousands of time. I havent even been using ollama during this time. I tried running ollama after seeing this and it runs fine. I have no idea why it says scheduled service. I checked and there a no crons scheduled on the device.
I see mention of Error: mkdir /mnt/disk1/ollama: permission denied. I did move ollama to another drive at this location since my main drive was running out of space.


You can type in a terminal systemctl list-unit-files | grep ollama to get more info on the service it's trying to start. It is not a cron job. Then see this answer for how to disable the service. https://askubuntu.com/a/19324/243321 Use the systemd part of the answer.

Do you know what ollama is? Do you need it?

Looking at https://github.com/ollama/ollama/blob/main/docs/linux.md I can see that the .service file shows for it to restart every 3 seconds, and since it is failing, until you stop the service from running it will continue to fill up your logs.  I would recommend stopping the service, go through the manual install listed on the page (there is a chance that ollama doesn't have the account it needs to access), and then try again.
