# How can I do chkconfig like in Fedora?

Tags: 11.04, services, upstart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Chkconfig alternative for Ubuntu Server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2263/chkconfig-alternative-for-ubuntu-server)

In Fedora I can do

```
$ chkconfig --list | grep ssh

Note: This output shows SysV services only and does not include native
      systemd services. SysV configuration data might be overridden by native
      systemd configuration.

sshd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

and it shows all run levels. Then I can use

```
chkconfig sshd on
```

or

```
chkconfig sshd off
```

How can I do the same in my Ubuntu 11.04? + How do i mention in which runlevel it should start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if Ubuntu uses Upstart, not all services have been migrated to it yet and hence the old System-V style init scripts (files in `/etc/init.d/`.)

According to the manual page of [`chkconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig), `off` and `on` are used for stopping or starting services, not disabling them.

- To start the SSH daemon (which is named `ssh`), run: `sudo start ssh`
- Similarly, to stop it: `sudo stop ssh`

To list the status of all services, use:
 (N.B. output is lengthy and goes to stderr)

```
sudo service --status-all 2>&1 | more
```

These commands work for both the Upstart scripts as well as for the services in `/etc/init.d/`.

Comment: chkconfig we use for always to start when system starts. Is this same when we use "sudo start ssh" will it always start in any runlevel?

Comment: How do i say which runlevel ssh should start? like chkconfig.

Comment: For services using `/etc/init.d/`, you could use `ls -1 /etc/rc?.d/*apache2`. Upstart scripts can be checked with `initctl show-config ssh`, it would show. Note that Upstart still places wrapper scripts in `/etc/init.d/` for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 2):

chkconfig is for sysv init system and Ubuntu uses upstart, to list all services and their status type `initctl list`. Currently there is no tool to enable or disable services in upstart so you have to manually rename the file in /etc/init so it doesn't end with .conf.

Comment: How do i say which runlevel?

Comment: Runlevels are different on Debian and Ubuntu (vs. RPM distros).  There really are only two effective runlevels.  1 and 2.  Level one is the same as single-user mode on (most) any Linux.  Runlevel 2 is what you would think of as 5 on Fedora.