# Is there an equivalent to `chkconfig --add` in Ubuntu?

Tags: glassfish

I don't have an IT background so be patient with me, please.

I have an Ansible file (.yml) for glassfish configuration service, that was built for CentOS.

I'm trying to "transform it" for use it with Ubuntu 14.04.

In the file I have this:

```
name: Execute shell script - configure service glassfish - chkconfig --add glassfish warn=no
      shell: chkconfig --add glassfish warn=no

    - name: Execute shell script - configure service glassfish - chkconfig glassfish on warn=no
      shell: chkconfig glassfish on warn=no

    - name: Start service glassfish
      service:
          name=glassfish
          state=started
```

I searched and found that `chkconfig` is not a valid command in Ubuntu.

What should I use to replace the following commands?

```
chkconfig --add glassfish warn=no
chkconfig glassfish on warn=no
```

Comment: [Possibly helpful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2263/chkconfig-alternative-for-ubuntu-server)

Answer (score -1):

```
update-rc.d <service> defaults
```

or

```
update-rc.d <service> start 20 3 4 5
```

Comment: But note that it is not valid for 16.04+ which changed to systemd.